# What is the meaning of "Although we may seem worlds away, I hope you know I am right there with you."?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of this sentence? Can anyone explain it to me please:

> Although we may seem worlds away, I hope you know I am right there with you.

I tried to google it and I understood that even if we are very far from each other you should know that I am with you by supporting you and caring about you.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include more detail as explained in the “Details, Please” link above, we should be able to take it off hold.

Comment: I should like to say to you that googling stuff cannot explain sentences. What are the parts you do not understand? Please parse the sentence: mark it in segments so you can ask questions about those parts you do not understand.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't understand the first part of the sentence.

Comment: @HussamHamdeh What's the source of this sentence? To me, it seems like it should be *worlds apart* not *worlds away*, and that it's being used metaphorically rather than literally. But only the context of the sentence can make that known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idiomatic expressions:

- **to be worlds away from something**

If I live in Brazil and you live in Lebanon, our lives are worlds away from each other.

The usual form of this expression is

* **to be worlds apart from something**.

- Science fiction and romance comedies (movies) are worlds apart.

These both mean that two people or things or two people's lives or experiences are very different and/or also very distant from each other. It can be meant literally or figuratively.